# Расстояние между буквами в HtmlLabel

Tags: c#

В тексте у `HtmlLabel` символ "-" дефис вплотную встает со следующей буквой. Как можно увеличить расстояние между буквами?

Пробовал `letter-spacing` прописать в div (`<div style='letter-spacing: 1em;'></div>`) - но оно не сработало.

**добавлено:**

Выяснил, что при разных размерах шрифта отображается то нормально, то слитно... Подозреваю что это от сглаживания зависит...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему решил заменив "-" на спецсимвол **`&ndash;`**. Другого способа не нашел.